# Advérbios sucessivos em -mente — origem de recurso estilístico

Tags: origem-histórica, advérbios

Dizem os gramáticos que quando, numa mesma oração ou frase, empregamos sucessivamente dois ou mais advérbios terminados em *-mente*, esta terminação ou sufixo só deve aparecer no último deles. Este recurso estilístico, concordam os gramáticos (e grande parte do universo lusófono, creio eu), torna o discurso mais conciso, mais elegante. Quando os lusófonos começaram a utilizar este recurso estilístico ou a que época ou primórdios ele remonta? Os hispanófonos já o utilizavam ou alguma vez o utilizaram?

Seguem abaixo alguns exemplos com este recurso estilístico:

- "Ao fugir da cadeia, fê-lo Poliponésio *astuta, inteligente e lindamente*, mas de igual forma a polícia o agarrou em menos de meia hora".
- "Andam na Poliponésia *vagarosa porém elegantemente* os poliponésios tidos por cidadãos exemplares".
- "Ao raiar da noite escura, adormecia o dia *agitada senão que desesperada e ansiosamente* aos pés dela, da noite, breu que a tudo iluminava".

Comment: Good question..

Answer (score 1):

The origin of most adverbs formed on adjectives in Portuguese is from a two word construction, the base adjective followed by the noun *mente*, used as an adverbial phrase.

*Mente* is a feminine noun. This is why the adjective, prior to be combined with *-mente* in modern Portuguese, is first placed in the feminine form.

As *mente* was a noun, it could take multiple adjectives. As it grammaticalized in the language, this characteristic was maintained (or alternatively we could say the grammaticalization isn't yet finished, because such words have two stresses, which is incredibly rare elsewhere [if such words exist?], but the norm for adverbs built from adjectives)

Comment: I’m pretty sure that [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18357/457) also applies here. :)