# Por que quando se forma um advérbio dum adjetivo, se usa o adjetivo no feminino?

Tags: advérbios, sufixos, feminino-masculino

Percebi que quando se forma um advérbio dum adjetivo, ele está no feminino:

> "brav**a**mente";
>
> "corajos**a**mente";
>
> "relacion**a**damente"; etc.

Isso acontece por que o substantivo "mente" é feminino e o sufixo para formar advérbios é "-mente"?

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18357/457), e [outra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4980/38).

Comment: @tchrist, ambos estão em inglês.

Comment: @tchrist Ótima tua resposta no Spanish SE, acho que é só transcrever traduzido aqui. :)

Comment: @Schilive A resposta à tua pergunta é essencialmente sim.

Comment: @stafusa Como querias, [essa postagem](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18357/457) já tem uma tradução. :)

Comment: @tchrist Hhahaha... OK, está chegando perto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto ocorre pois o sufixo "-mente" vem literalmente de "mente", portanto, "com mente corajosa" = "corajosamente".

Resposta bem curtinha, mas creio que o suficiente. :)