# É verdade que advérbios com o sufixo "-mente" tem duas sílabas mais fortes?

Tags: fonologia, advérbios

Vi, em [Advérbios sucessivos em -mente — origem de recurso estilístico](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/adv%c3%a9rbios-sucessivos-em-mente-origem-de-recurso-estil%c3%adstico?noredirect=1&lq=1), que advérbios terminados em "-mente" têm duas sílabas tónicas.

Seria como se "corajosamente" fosse escrita como "'corajósamênte'"? Ou essa palavra possui uma sílaba subtônica?

Pelo que sei, é muito comum, palavras criadas a partir doutras palavras terem uma sílaba subtônica.

Resumo: a transcrição fonética generalizada de "corajosamente" é [koɾɐˌʒɔ.zɐˈmẽ.t͡ʃɪ] ou [koɾɐʒɔzɐˈmẽ.t͡ʃɪ]?

Comment: Eu pessoalmente não entendo a diferença entre duas sílabas tónicas ou uma tónica e uma subtónica, mas... será que a pronuncia mais comum é [k**u**rɐˌʒɔ.zɐˈmẽ.tʃɪ]? E se for, talvez assim aparece outra maneira de ver este efeito—a redução de todos os vogais, menos aqueles em sílabas tónicas ou subtónicas. (Ou será que esta redução não é "generalizada"?)

Comment: @DanGetz, eu só ouvi portugueses falando [kuɾɐˌʒɔ.zɐˈmẽ.tʃɪ], nunca brasileiros. Mas isso não me impede de estar errado.

Comment: @DanGetz, eu, na realidade, não falo [koɾɐˌʒɔ.zɐˈmẽ.t͡ʃɪ]; falo [korɐˌʒɔzaˈmẽŋ.t͡ʃɪ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resposta

Na página 61 do livro Gramática Normativa da Língua Portuguesa, 49ª edição, de Carlos Henrique Rocha Lima, diz:

> Porém, vocábulos de mais de três sílabas, sobretudo os derivados, possuem, quase sempre, além do acento principal, um ou mais acentos secundários. A mais perceptível das sílabas entre as que trazem acento secundário (e somente até aí costuma ir a análise) — denomina-se subtônica.

Idem dá-nos exemplos:

> *admi**rá**vel* + *-MENte* = admi**rá**velMENte (sílaba tônica: *-MEN*; sílaba subtônica: -**rá**);
>
> *gene**ro**s(o)* + *i* + *DAde* = *gene**ro**siDAde* (sílaba tônica: *-DA*; sílaba subtônica: *-**ro***).

#### Curiosidade

Entre (1&2) 1943 e 1971, (2) Brasil mantinha o acento em palavras sufixadas por *-mente* ou por sufixos começados em "z" ("-zeiro", por exemplo); porém, se o mantido acento fosse agudo (*´*), tornava-se grave (*`*). A ABL dá-nos exemplos:

> *avó* + *-zinha* = *avòzinha*;
>
> *cortês* + *-mente* = *cortêsmente*;
>
> *leões* + *-zinhos* = *leõezinhos*;
>
> *voluntário* + *-zinho* = *voluntàriozinho*;
>
> *café* + *-zeiro* = *cafèzeiro*;
>
> *volúvel* + *-mente* = *volùvelmente*;
>
> *faísca* + *-zinha* = *faìscazinha*.

Estes acentos mantidos e os tornados em acento grave indicavam sílaba subtônica. Esses acentos sempre estão antes da sílaba tônica, por isso são chamados de "pretônicos".

(1): https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formul%C3%A1rio_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1943;

(2): https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/formulario-ortografico;

Answer (score 0):

Olá, **Schilive**!

Então, como você mesmo disse, as palavras terminadas em mente possuem uma sílaba tônica e uma sílaba subtônica. Tomando como exemplo a palavra "corajosamente", **men** seria nossa sílaba tônica e **jo** seria a subtônica.